# React slick slider event on beforechange

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I want to get from which element before change fires when clicking on arrow and pagination react slick

```
 const settings = {
    beforeChange: (prevSlide, currentSlide, event) => {
      
      console.log(event)
    },
    }
```